# Function and its derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

It is known that $\dfrac{{\rm d} F(x)}{{\rm d} x}\to\infty$ when $x\to\alpha$. Then based on this, can we have $F(x)\to\infty$ when $x\to\alpha$? Here, $\alpha$ is a constant. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, you're expressing $F$ as a function of one variable, so that the partial derivative and normal derivative are identical!

Consider the function $F(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ and $\alpha=0.$

---

**Added**: In case it is relevant (which depends entirely on what you meant by your post, as Barry Cipra points out), you should also consider the function $$G(x)=-\frac{1}{F(x)}$$ (where $F$ is as above) on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},$ with $\alpha=0$ again.

Comment: Yes, it should be the normal derivative. Your example is great!

Comment: But doesn't $\sqrt[3]x\to0$ instead of $\infty$ when $x\to0$?

Comment: @Barry: Yes. But the derivative....

Comment: But the OP is asking if $F(x)\to\infty$.

Comment: @Barry: Right. Hence, we have a counterexample.

Comment: But the OP is asking *can* we have, not *do* we have.  (Or can we *have*, not can we *conclude*.)

Comment: @Barry: True. For some reason, I assumed that the OP was misusing the word "have" to mean "have as a consequence" (*i.e.*: "conclude"). I will amend my answer accordingly, just in case my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, my question is not clear (it should be "can we conclude") but the answer of Cameron Buie is good and comprehensive.